# SSAS - process top 10K rows of fact table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas

My environment: SQL Server 2005 for database and SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services.

I have a fact table of 78M rows. I want to only process the first 10K rows in my development phase.

Other than removing the rows from my Fact table, is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: I would not consider developing against such a small data set since it is very likely that the code you write would not perform well on the larger set. If you are going to run code against a large data set on production it is imperative that you write the code against a data set of similar size in dev.

Comment: My general idea is to develop my calculations and other columns etc based on a small(er) subset, and then have it to process the whole 78M overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Data Source View, right click the Table Name, choose "Replace Table / Named Query" and in the query, use TOP N

**EDIT**

Once you do this, if you add Named Calculations to it, and then you replace the Named Query back with a Table, you lose your Named Calculations. Something to be careful about!

Comment: Or directly reference the view instead of a named query.  Then there is no issue with the Named Calcuations since you don't have to update the dsv to test changes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Raj on changing to Named Query. You could also build the top N into a database view and then add or remove TOP N from the view without having to change the deployed analysis services cube. Or you could point the view at a separate table that contains the 10K rows.

Another alternative would be to keep the DSV as it is, but change the partition on the Measure Group to use a TOP N or alternatively a trimmed down table. Then just change the partition back when you want to process all rows.

The benefits of using a separate table to duplicate the 10K rows is that you're going to guarantee you get the same results each time (TOP N doesn't) and so testing the results may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

there is one more thing can be done if, Use Aggregations tab and Calculate the aggregations.
Keep the size limit to 1 -2 MB.
So it will calculate very less members in the partition.